# GitAhead - Can I "open existing repository" into a "Remote" list?

Tags: gitahead

This question is about the [GitAhead](https://gitahead.github.io/gitahead.com/) GUI for Git.  I'm posting here on SO by suggestion from their website.

I cloned a repository from GitLab with the command line. I added it to the left-hand pane of GitAhead by clicking `+` and `Open Existing Repository`.  As expected, it appears in the "Open" and "Recent" lists.

The repository is also listed in "Remote" under my GitLab account, but with a "download from cloud" icon.  Thus it does not recognize that the repository which I already added corresponds with the remote repository, despite that my existing clone has the same name and the appropriate SSH remote origin.  **How do I make GitAhead recognize that my existing repository is a clone from my GitLab account, so that it opens when I double-click the corresponding entry under "Remote"?**

My attempts are:

1. Double-clicking on the remote repository entry leads to a "Clone Repository" dialog.  I tried pointing this to the existing clone, but it failed because the directory was nonempty.
2. I edited `GitAhead.conf` and added a line under `[remote]` of the form `gitlab\username\repo-name=/path/to/clone`. This is fine for one time, but I'd like to learn how to do it from the GUI if possible.

Am I missing something, or is this not yet a feature?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

**First:**

Commit and push all changes using your current GIT tool, then clone the repository to that same location from GITAhead.

**Second:**

Copy all files from your local repository to a temporary location, then clone the repository from GITAhead and move all files back into the now synchronized directory.

The second solution permits you to keep uncommitted changes as such until you deem it is time to commit.